# Sending a text/notification with Arduino + ESP8266 Wifi shield

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

Is it possible to send a text message using an Arduino and the Sparkfun ESP8266 Wifi Shield using Temboo? I noticed that the ESP8266 might not be supported by Temboo and I was wondering if there is a workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I work at Temboo.

While we don't officially support the ESP8266, we've found a couple of forum posts in which people have been able to get Temboo to work with the ESP8266. Here you go:

http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?p=24019

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=337186.0

If that doesn't help, feel free to contact Temboo Support and we'll do our best to help figure out what's going wrong for you.

The key piece of info you need to be aware of is that you need to modify following Temboo library files:

```
\Arduino\libraries\Temboo\src\Temboo.cpp

\Arduino\libraries\Temboo\src\utility\
--ChoreoInputFormatter
--ChoreoOutputFormatter
--ChoreoPresetFormatter
--TembooSession
--tmbhmac
--tmbmd5
```

You need to modify all occurrences of `"avr/pgmspace.h"` in these files, changing it to `"pgmspace.h"`.

Comment: Could you add a folder called avr and a file called pgmspace.h with `#include "..\pgmspace.h"` in?  If you could that would save re making the change if you updated the Tembo library.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Matt. I'll certainly pass it on to our dev team.

Comment: I meant for the original poster, but if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, apparently you can.

I did a quick search on Google and found a GitHub library for the ESP8266 https://github.com/sabas1080/TembooForESP8266 and a post on the Arduino Forum https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=337186.0 that says you can download a skeleton program and hack that.